# How to sort an array with one exception in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, asort

Let's say I have an array called $array that looks like this once I run asort on it:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Apples
    [2] => Bananas
    [3] => Cherries
    [4] => Donuts
    [5] => Eclairs
    [6] => Fried_Chicken
)
```

What is the simplest way to make it so that, after sorting alphabetically, the key that has the value "Donuts" is removed and then put at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this.  Tested it and confirmed it works.  Reordered your array so I could actually see the sorting.

```
$arr = Array(
  1 => "Fried_Chicken",
  2 => "Donuts",
  3 => "Bananas",
  4 => "Apples",
  5 => "Eclairs",
  6 => "Cherries"
);  

// Get donut and key
$donut_key = array_search("Donuts", $arr);
$donut = $arr[$donut_key];  // If you don't need to keep the value, skip this line

// Remove donut
unset($arr[$donut_key]);

// Sort
asort($arr);

// Append Donut
$arr += array($donut_key => $donut);
```

Array Search
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Key preserving append
http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/php-array_merge-preserving-numeric-keys/

Comment: Thanks that's sort of what I ended up doing too.

Comment: Yeah, took me a bit longer than I planned...  sorry about that.  Just figured a full code example would be helpful to future googlers

Answer (score 6):

I would simply remove the donut element, perform your `asort`, and then add the donut item back on.

Comment: I get this array from data that is variable so the next time I run this, Donuts may be #2 or #8, so I can't unset($array[4]).

Comment: You don't need to `unset($array[4])` there are a handful of different ways made available by PHP to remove an unneeded element from the array. It will probably take 2 minutes of Googling to find one suitable to your needs.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, then when I couldn't figure it out by looking at php.net I asked here how to remove it from the array.

Comment: I figured it out by doing this $key = array_search('Donuts', $array); unset($array['key']);

Comment: There you go, but it should be `unset($array[$key])` in your last example.